# Llamar a una función desde un botón

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Muy buenas a todos, estoy tratando de llamar mi función que he creado dentro de un componente de React para que guarde el correo y contraseña que el usuario haya colocado dentro de los cuadros de texto, el problema es que una vez que llamo la función dentro de la declaración de mi botón esta hace caso omiso.

```
var contraseñaFE = "";
var correoFE = "";

function getInformation()
{
    correoFE = document.getElementById("Ctxt").value;
    contraseñaFE = document.getElementById("Ptxt").value;
    document.getElementById("txt1").innerHTML=correoFE;
    document.getElementById("txt2").innerHTML=contraseñaFE;
    alert("sadasdasd");
}

class Login extends Component{
 render(){
   return(
     <nav className="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
     <p className="Log-menu">Correo electronico <input id="Ctxt" className="Log-Ctxt" type="text"/>&nbsp; &nbsp; Contraseña: <input  id="Ptxt" className="Log-Ctxt" type="text"/> &nbsp; &nbsp; <input type="button" value="Entrar" className="Bt-join" onclick="getInformation();" /></p>
     <img src={logo} className="Log-logo" alt="logo" />
     <div id="txt1" >HELLO</div>
     <div id="txt2">HELLO2</div>
     </nav>
   );
 }
}
```

Comment: Si no recuerdo mal, has de usar `onClick` como atributo y no `onclick`

Comment: No uses nunca `var contraseñaFE ` caracteres especiales en variables (ñ) puede que te genere error en algunos browsers

Comment: @PabloLozano has puesto duplicada una pregunta que no fue contestada y hasta es del mismo usuario...

Comment: @Roy Lo sé: el mismo usuario ha escrito dos veces la misma pregunta. Es la definición de *duplicada*. Una de las dos debería ser borrada

Comment: @PabloLozano Ok, entendido, gracias.